# multiple Regex line changes: duplicate, replace and delete parts

Tags: regex, replace, sed, awk

I have text file:

```
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext
```

I want copy duplicate each string and make some replacements to get this:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file3.ext
```

I've made script, whitch delete leading path and duplicate string:

```
sed -e 's/\/path\/to\/delete\///' -e 's/.\+/\0 \0/'  list.txt
```

Now I've got this:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext
```

But a have no idea to replace slashes after space.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|/path/to/delete/(.*)|\1 \1|;:a;s|/([^ /]*/[^ /]*)$|-\1|;ta' file
```

Delete require pattern and then duplicate the string.

Work backwards through the second string replacing all but the last `/` with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the hold space:

```
sed -e 's%/path/to/delete/%%;h;s%/%-%g;x;G;s/\n/ /'
```

The `h` copies the pattern space (the name after the leading path is deleted) to the hold space.  Replace the slashes with dashes in the pattern space.  Exchange (`x`) the pattern and hold spaces.  Concatenate the hold space after the pattern space with a newline (`G`).  Replace the newline by a space.

That replaces one too many slashes...but the change is 'trivial' if you know about branching in `sed` too.

```
sed -e 's%/path/to/delete/%%;h;: redo;s%/\(.*/.*\)%-\1%g;t redo;x;G;s/\n/ /'
```

The difference is in the presence of `: redo` which creates a label `redo`; the `t redo` which jumps to the label `redo` if a substitute operation changed anything since the last test; and in the more complex regex which matches a slash (which is not remembered) followed by any material that contains a slash (which is remembered).  The unremembered slash is replaced by a dash.  It is possible to omit the space after the colon, and also the space after `t`.  I'm not convinced it is good practice to do so.  I'd probably also split that up into separate commands to make it easier to understand:

```
sed -e 's%/path/to/delete/%%' \
    -e 'h' \
    -e ': redo' \
    -e 's%/\(.*/.*\)%-\1%g' \
    -e 't redo' \
    -e 'x' \
    -e 'G' \
    -e 's/\n/ /'
```

Or:

```
sed -e 's%/path/to/delete/%%
        h
        : redo
        s%/\(.*/.*\)%-\1%g
        t redo
        x
        G
        s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: An alternative to the looping part of the solution might be to use greed and replace the last `/` with a unique character or phrase (perhaps `\n`), translate all `/`'s to `-`'s and then replace the unique character or phrase with a `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; s%/path/to/delete/%%; print "$_ "; s%/%-% while 1 < y=/==; print "$_\n";'
```

It just keeps replacing `/` with a `-` while there is enough slashes. It also works separately with the second copy to make the work easier.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `s%/(?=.*/)%-%g` to substitute all but the last `/` without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

#### Content of script.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="/"
}
{
    for (i=5;i<NF;i++) {
        printf "%s/" ,$i
    }
    printf "%s " ,$NF
}
{
    for (i=5;i<NF-1;i++) {
        printf "%s-", $i
    }
    printf "%s/%s\n" ,$(NF-1),$NF
}
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext
/path/to/delete/dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext
$ awk -f script.awk file
dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file3.ext
```

With `gawk`:

```
$ gawk '{
    printf ("%s ", gensub(/\/path\/to\/delete\//,"","G",$0)); 
    printf ("%s\n", gensub(/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/,"\\4-\\5-\\6\/\\7","G",$0))
}' file
```

#### Test:

```
gawk '{printf ("%s ", gensub(/\/path\/to\/delete\//,"","G",$0)); printf "%s\n", gensub(/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/,"\\4-\\5-\\6\/\\7","G",$0) }' file
dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file3.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a bit of a dirty hack, but it's <strike>simple</strike> as simple as you can get with `sed` and should be just enough for your task:

```
$ sed -r -e 's@/path/to/delete/@@; h; s@(.+)/(.*)@\1\n\2@; s@/@-@g; s@(.+)\n(.+)@\1/\2@; x; G; s/\n/ /' list.txt
dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.ext dir1-dir2-dir3/file3.ext
```

Comment: I'm waiting for [potong](http://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) to see if he/she can outsimple this haha

Comment: @doubleDown I'm by no means a `sed`-guru =). If I were to choose a tool, I'd do this in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Another bash solution

```sh
while read path; do
    path=${path#/path/to/delete/}
    file=${path##*/}
    dir=${path%/*}
    printf "%s %s/%s\n" "$path" "${dir//\//-}" "$file"
done < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed (no jump)

```
sed -r 's./path/to/delete/..;h;s./([^/]*)$.|\1.;s./.-.g;s.\|./.;x;G;s/\n/ /' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with bash only:

Split the path into directory and filename using `dirname` and `basename`, change the slashes in the directory path to dashes using `tr`, then concatenate the result.

```
➤ for f in "dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext" "dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.ext" "dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext" "dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.ext"; 
do 
   echo "$(dirname $f | tr '/' '-')/$(basename $f)" ; 
done
dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1-dir2-dir3/file1.ext
dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
dir1-dir2-dir3/file2.ext
```

Sometime, what you need isn't a hammer.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you need 3 hammers